# $root in knockout.js resolve to blank page

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using the $root binding context and it resolve to a blank page.
when removing it, the page loads fine.

Resolve to blank page:

```
<td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
<td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
<td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
```

Works fine:

```
<td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
<td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
```

Example from here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/29940/
(in my code it doesn't work but on jsfiddle it does).
Can't find what is the problem

Comment: You'll need to provide an [mcve] in the question itself for us to be able to help you + the question to remain useful to others with the same problem. (PS. Possibly a language issue, but by "resolve to blank page", do you perhaps mean "doesn't render anything in the browser window"?)

Comment: I've removed my answer since it probably wasn't helping - so I'll just add this as a comment to suggest that it might be the case: It looks like your $root might be pointing at window object, and something interferes with it - you can see if re-writing the object instantiation helps, `var app = new Vm();  ko.applyBindings(app);` In OP example, instantiating your object directly in ko (`ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());`) could cause similar issues. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you both. You are right but the code is too messy to for providing it. I though that I did some trivial mistake but I found that the problem was related to <PERL> section in the  html code. Adding backslash before the dollar sign `\$root` solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I though that I did some trivial mistake but I found that the problem was related to  section in the html code. Adding backslash before the dollar sign `\$root` solved the problem.

Comment: On one hand: thanks for sharing your answer. On the other hand, this answer is not at all related to the question as posted. If a future visitor finds the question because she/he's having the same problem, it's very unlikely that this answer will be helpful.